# How to make Alert action title-less

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I want to remove a title section from an Alert action.
Making title string `""` won't remove the title section

```
@IBAction func addImage(sender: AnyObject!) {

    let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "" ,message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openCamera()
    }
    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openGallary()
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
        {
            UIAlertAction in

    }

    // Add the actions
    alert.addAction(cameraAction)
    alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present the controller
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

How can I remove the title section all together?

Comment: Have you tried passing 'nil' instead of an empty string? It is an optional value

Comment: ahh..that worked. If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"title" is an optional value, if you pass nil instead of the empty string, it will get rid of the title area.

`let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil ,message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)`

Comment: fantastic tip !  :)